# Knitr/Kable: Html Table Width

Tags: r, knitr, kable

I have one html table with a bunch of cols. I would like to expand the table as much as I can to fit in this columns. My output and code are below. As you can see theres' a low of white space between the table. I would like to use such space.

```
d %>%
kable( align = c( 'l', rep( 'c', 23  )), escape = F, full_width = F ) %>%
kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", 'condensed' ), font_size = 10 )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `full_width` option to `full_width = T`